# Dockerfile How to set filename to env

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way in a dockerfile to set the name of the filename to a env?

For example below is my docker file. I want to only print out the portion of this name of the file `Test`. Everyfile name will look the same but the text before _ will be different.

For example there can be `Test_0.1.zip Hello_0.1.zip Moon_0.1.zip`

How can i take out the text from the filename such as `Test Hello Or Moon`and set it to a ENV in the dockerfile?

```
FROM openjdk

ADD Test_0.1.zip .
RUN unzip Test_0.1.zip
```

Comment: run container with --env-file directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.env` file and set filename there eg.

.env file:

`FILE_NAME=<filename>`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk

ADD ${FILE_NAME}_0.1.zip .
RUN unzip ${FILE_NAME}_0.1.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to substitute the first part of your filename with a variable.

You can achieve this with build args. Here is an example:

```
FROM openjdk
ARG filename
ADD ${filename}_0.1.zip .
RUN unzip ${filename}_0.1.zip
```

To build your image, you have to specify the build tag:

```
docker build -t myimage --build-arg filename=foo .
```

reference:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: Right answer. Although that kind of use (Docker as a provisioner) is discouraged, for the image consistency. ARG appeared lately, mainly to allow people to work around specific issues such as configuring a proxy when building an image. Docker right approach (compatible with their tooling) would be to create distinct branches on a repo.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to extract a portion of an input filename, and set it to an environment variable.

Each `RUN` will open up a new shell, so you can't share env variables between them. And you also cannot assign an `ENV` based on the output of a `RUN`

Your best bet would be to create an `ENTRYPOINT` script, which does it for you. For example:

Define an `entrypoint.sh` script which extracts the text:

```
export FILE_TEXT=$(echo $filename | grep -o -e "Text\|Hello\|Moon")
```

With your `Dockerfile` passing in the filename argument to the entrypoint:

```
FROM openjdk
ARG filename
ENV ${filename}
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash entrypoint.sh
```